# What's the easiet way to detect "evil twins" in Rational ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I'm using ClearCase 7.1

I suspect we have some evil twins. I'm looking for the most efficient way to find them out by scanning the VOB or any other ways. Is there any script that applies it?

For the next coming evil twins we'll use a trigger that prevents it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you benefit from the integrated evil twin detection from ClearCase 8.0, the only way remains [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) command:

See "[About Evil Twins, "locate" section](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21125072#locate)" for some examples:

you run the following command from two views and compare the output (oid and pname), you can verify whether there is an evil twin situation on a file level:

> Windows syntax example:

```
cleartool find . -type f -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%On, %n\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%@@\""
```

> Unix syntax example:

```
cleartool find . -type f -exec 'cleartool describe -fmt "%On, %En\\n" $CLEARCASE_PN@@'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get the output for each file separately?

Comment: @user986086 no, this query is much more to list *all* files and make comparison based on that result. But you can try and put a '`>`' (redirect) within the exec directive if you want, and try to redirect to a `tmp` folder, using `$CLEARCASE_PN` as a filename.